# Scroll to the correct tap / click position in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a collapsible set and each collabsible holds a listview of 10 - 100 items. If I tap one of the items a panel opens. The bad thing is that the page is scrolled to the top. How can I return to have the tapped / clicked listview item at the same position before panel opens?

I've tried:

```
Ypos = $(this).offset().top; // store before panel opens


$.mobile.silentScroll(Ypos); // set after panel closes
```

But this will set the listview item at top of the screen, wich is close to what I want but not perfect...

So I tried to store the Y-position of the mousepointer and did:

```
Ypos = $(this).offset().top + (e.clientY / 10); // "Better" but not good..
```

So here I'm stuck. "10" was just for test, as it will scroll too far otherwise.
Any ideas?

Comment: are you calling `silentScroll` after panel is closed?

Comment: Yes. But let's say my listview has 100 items, and i'm at 50 at center of screen. I can get the 50th item to be at top of screen. I just need it to be at the position before i clicked it... So it's Offset + (old_position_relative_to current window height)... or something

Comment: if that item is at the bottom of the screen, you can scroll to its' exact position, as screen isn't scrollable after that stage.

Comment: I know but it's not at bottom. It's center of screen when i click (with at least 49 items above, and 50 below). After the position is not restored. I can get it to be at top of viewport, but it needs to be current viewport + some extra pixels

Comment: have you listened to `panelclose` event to run `silentScroll`?

Comment: I have a button on the panel. When I click it, the panel closes + some other stuff

Comment: var pos = $(document).scrollTop(); and then after close the panel: scroll to pos :-) works...